# Getting the selected item text in struts 2

Tags: struts2

I have a ui tag select

```
<s:select list="studentList" name="selectedstudent" listKey="studentID"
    listValue="studentName" headerKey="0" 
    headerValue="--All Student--" theme="simple"></s:select>
```

in java code i have `selectedstudent` returns let say 4 how can I get the name of student in java.

Comment: So do you need just name or id **and** name?

Comment: both , as of now i can only get the id

Comment: Repopulate studentList (by reloading it from db, session, anywhere), then get the object at the selected index.

Comment: You cannot submit both w/o using some js or parsing a string. Submit id and in class get name from somewhere.

Comment: @AleksandrM then in js on select change i set the text to hidden field  and get that field value in java

Comment: @Haider: Yes, you can do this. But it is better to submit id and retrieve other details in class.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name by id in `selectedstudent`. For this purpose if you don't have a students list in your action, you should load them from database. Otherwise searching a `Student` object by id would return a name if you provide a getter for the object. Keep in mind that you have already specified a `listValue` as `studentName`. This value should be taken from a `Student` and thus a list should be `List<Student>` as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your studentList is in session you can retrieve student name as follow (your code may be different):

```
List<Student> studentList = (List<Student>)ActionContext.getContext().getSession().get("studentList");
//You should ovveride equals(and hashCode) to point the Student equality to studentID
//You should also check if studentList.indexOf(selectedstudent) != -1
Student student = studentList.get(studentList.indexOf(selectedstudent));
String studentName = student.getStudentName();
```

Answer (score 0):

Business layer

Student.java (model)

```
public class Student {
   //Getter and Setter Method.
    private String id;
    private String name;
    public Student(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

struts.xml

```
  <action name="list_action" class="controller.ListAction">
        <result name="success">struts_select.jsp</result>
  </action>
```

package controller;

ListAction.java

```
   private List<Student> student_list = new ArrayList<Student>();//Getter and Setter
   @Override
   public String execute() throws Exception {
      //do your stuff
      //list collect from database.
      student_list=(List<Student>) criteria.list();
    }
```

struts_select.jsp

```
    <s:select label="Student List" 
              listKey="id"  //use your Student.java member variable of id signature
              listValue="name"  //use your Student.java member variable of name signature
      headerKey="0" headerValue="Select student Name"
      list="s" 
      name="student_info" />
```